# Didn't Get Expected Layout in Landscape Mode Using Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, android-constraintlayout, landscape

I'm fairly new to android development. I have a very simple Login-like page. Here is the picture:
[image]

Here what it looks like in landscape(blueprint) :

[image]

Here what it looks like in the actual device:
[image]

There is just too much space between the two buttons and they are not aligned perfectly. And also if there are more elements, they go outside of my screen.

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.04"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PasswordInput"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PasswordInput"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="246dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PasswordInput"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.63"
    android:text="Forgot Password"
    android:textAlignment="center"

    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/UserNameInput"
    android:layout_width="339dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:hint="User Name"
    android:inputType="text"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/PasswordInput"
    android:layout_width="339dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/UserNameInput" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Kindly help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

You are using hardcoded sized for your views (`android:layout_width="339dp"`).
when you rotate the screen its width and height are changing, and that `339dp` that looked good before will look totally different for landscape.

If you want to make your views responsive you can use:

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.xx"
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.yy"
```

And now your views will be responsive.

---

For example:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/UserNameInput"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/UserNameInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:hint="User Name"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/PasswordInput"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/UserNameInput"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Forgot Password"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PasswordInput"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.63"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5"/>
```

[image]

[image]